# datetime lowest value find

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have some DateTime values with me. How can I pick the lowest date from the values and which array has contained that value.

```
DateTime file1date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[0].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime file2date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[1].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime file3date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[2].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime file4date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[3].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime file5date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[4].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime file6date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[5].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Instead of creating 6 different variables to test one by one, add the result to a `List<DateTime>` then use Min extension to find the lowest one

Comment: Start by placing them in a array or list?  `filedate[0] = DateTime.ParseExact(....)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
List<DateTime> fileDate = new List<DateTime>();
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
   fileDate.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[i].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
DateTime minVal = fileDate.Min();
int minIndex = fileDate.IndexOf(minVal);
```

Comment: i haven't downvote you it is appearing like this only and i am not able to change it .

Comment: @RahulSingh Oh, I know it wasn't you, don't worry, that's why I put downvoter, because there is no way of knowing who it was.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an array for the file dates as well.
This also enables you to get the lowest value while populating the array:

```
var filesDate = new DateTime[fileListfordiff.Length];
var lowestDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
var lowestDateIndex = -1;
for(int i=0; i < fileListfordiff.Length; i++)
{
    filesDate[i] = DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[i].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if(filesDate[i] < lowestDate)
    {
        lowestDate = filesDate[i];
        lowestDateIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [`MoreLINQ`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), consider this approach:

```
var fileDate = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    fileDate.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(fileListfordiff[i].Substring(22, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

var arrayIndex = fileDate
    .Select((value, index) => new {index, value})
    .MinBy(z => z.value).index;
```

The `Select` call allows you to get the value and index at the same time, and `MinBy` allows you to get the entry with the lowest value.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net7 you can do the following:

```
    DateTime highestDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
    DateTime lowestDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Result on my system is:
highest date: 31-12-9999 23:59:59
lowest date: 1-1-0001 00:00:00.